# Formatting inventory of parts

Tags: python, csv

I have one file with indexes.  For example, they are:

> ```
> 1    Fruit
> 2    Meat
> 3    Fish        
> 4    Salmon
> 5    Pork
> 6    Apple
> ```

And a dictionary, because I want to match entries that I choose:

```python
similar = {'1' : '6', '2' : '5'}
```

Since they are on the same file, my program scans for the `'1'` on the file, and then re-scans from the beginning looking for the `'6'`. Same with all the numbers, always re-scanning.

It's a very large file with a lot of numbers.

```python
similar = { '4719' : '4720c01' }

for aline in invFormatted:
    lines = aline.split("\t") #Splits the CSV file on every tab.
    lotID = lines[0]
    partNO = lines[1] #Splits and gets the part that would be the "index"
    if similar.has_key(partNO):
        for alines in invFormatted:
            liness = alines.split("\t")
            lotIDmatch = liness[0]
            partNOmatch = liness[1]
            if liness[1] == similar[partNO]:
```

Would there be a way to make it so it only scans it once?  Or any other ideas to put better this program?

There is a text file formatted this way:

> ```
> 51689299  4719    Medium Azure    Riding Cycle
> 51689345  4720c01 Trans-Clear Wheel & Tire Assembly
> ```

In real life, it would have thousands of entries.

Then, my Python file 'knows' that the part number 4719 matches the part number 4720c01 via the `similar` dictionary:

```python
similar = { '4719' : '4720c01' }
```

Now, what I think does:

```python
invFormatted = open('export.txt', 'r') #Opens the file with the part numbers

with open ('upload.txt', 'a') as upload:

    upload.write("<INVENTORY>") #Something that would be on the export

    for aline in invFormatted:
        lines = aline.split("\t") #Splits the text file on every tab
        lotID = lines[0] #The lot ID is the first word
        partNO = lines[1] #Part number the second one
        if partNO in similar: #Sees if the part number in question has a match, if YES
            for alines in invFormatted: #Searchs my inventory file again to see if the match is in my inventory
                liness = alines.split("\t")
                lotIDmatch = liness[0]
                partNOmatch = liness[1]
                if liness[1] == similar[partNO]: #if YES, prints out what I want it to print, and goes back to the first step
                    upload.write("blabla")

    invFormatted.close()

    upload.write("\n</INVENTORY>")
```

Comment: `#Splits the CSV file on every ","` - no it doesn't. It splits the lines on every tab. Also, if this is supposed to be CSV, [there's a module for that](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Your example code doesn't demonstrate the double-scanning your question is about. Could you provide a different example?

Comment: Of course, that comment was actually from another file I had where it splitted them on the commas. Always a module for that. :-)

Comment: The simple thing to do is to read the whole file in memory to a dict, and do your lookup there. If the file is too big to fit in memory, you can use pytables with an indexed column. Or even simpler; if the numbers are always continuously counting from 1, you can simply seek for the correct line in the file.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn, so, something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary PS the file actually has 3 variables, can you do a 3 variable dict?

Comment: what is the task in the whole? What goes after `if liness[1] == similar[partNO]:`? May be you should use something like indexed files or similar? Or you can save file positiion in dictionary and then use `seek()` and `readline()` methods to read desired line

Comment: @DenisNikanorov The files that I am scanning are inventory files. I have a lot of different parts in inventory, however, some of them match (should be used together). I have a something with the part numbers that should go together. All I want to do is, 1. check if the part has a match, 2. Take the info from that match and, say, export it.

Comment: dicts are always key->value; but value can be whatever you want it to be. For instance, a tuple of two things. If you file does infact describe a complex table with many columns, I would again advice to look at pytables. As noted by denis, a more complete description of what you are trying to do might help.

Comment: Brick: that sounds very database-y.  There are tons of database tools out there for python; check it out, it might make your whole project a lot simpler. If you insist on the current file format though, you basically have to read in all into memory for efficient search. Fundamentally, you cant quickly jump to a given line using a textfile, because you don't know the length of the lines in advance. Or perhaps you could search for newline chars, and then do a binary search on indexes. But textfiles and database operations fundamentally have a square peg and round hole feel to them.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Full code posted with annotations. It is indeed something to be done with databases, but I get the inventory file as a simple TXT with tabs. It has around 4K entries, so not a billion, but it'd take some time if there were a lot of matches.

Comment: For 4K entries, just read the whole thing into memory. You've already written the parsing code, but just write it to a dict once, and then lookup should no longer be a problem. That is; 

inventory = dict(line.split('\t')[:2] for line in invFormatted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rebuild your *similar* dictionary to be two-way:

```
complement = {v:k for k, v in similar.iteritems()}
similar.update(complement)
```

You may skip second pass (BTW, drop has_key - it is an old form):

```
if part_no in similar:
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you store the content in the CSV file in the memory?It will be more effective to read from the memory than the disk.

Maybe the CSV file will also be store in the memory cache by OS, but you can do it your self to make it more reliable.

Of course it's only when there is enough memory you can do this.

OK, from your code, I think maybe you just need to read all line[1] in and then scan it.

```
partNOs=[line.split("\t")[1] for line in upload]
for partNO in partNOs:
    if partNO in similar and similar[partNO] in partNOs:
        upload.write("blabla")
```

This assume that: what you write to file 'upload' will not match similar keys and values. Because it read the file and use the 'cache' before write into it.

Comment: Yes, it's not *that* big. They are approximately 10K lines, about 5 MB.

Comment: @BrickTop Add some code according to you code.